# Get Twitter Following Count

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

Im creating a widget for a Wordpress site and i am trying to get the twitter following count, I can get the followers count which is taken from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/displaying-the-total-number-of-twitter-followers-as-text-on-wordpress/. Any help would be great.

thanks Pierce

Current code in functions.php:

```
    // Twitter
    function getTwitterFollowers($screenName = 'hellowWorld')
    {
    // some variables
    $consumerKey = 'hidden';
    $consumerSecret = 'hidden';
    $token = get_option('cfTwitterToken');

    // get follower count from cache
    $numberOfFollowers = get_transient('cfTwitterFollowers');

    // cache version does not exist or expired
    if (false === $numberOfFollowers) {
    // getting new auth bearer only if we don't have one
    if(!$token) {
        // preparing credentials
        $credentials = $consumerKey . ':' . $consumerSecret;
        $toSend = base64_encode($credentials);

        // http post arguments
        $args = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'httpversion' => '1.1',
            'blocking' => true,
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $toSend,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
            ),
            'body' => array( 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' )
        );

        add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');
        $response = wp_remote_post('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', $args);

        $keys = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));

        if($keys) {
            // saving token to wp_options table
            update_option('cfTwitterToken', $keys->access_token);
            $token = $keys->access_token;
        }
    }
    // we have bearer token wether we obtained it from API or from options
    $args = array(
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $token"
        )
    );

    add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false');
    $api_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=$screenName";
    $response = wp_remote_get($api_url, $args);

    if (!is_wp_error($response)) {
        $followers = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
        $numberOfFollowers = $followers->followers_count;
    } else {
        // get old value and break
        $numberOfFollowers = get_option('cfNumberOfFollowers');
        // uncomment below to debug
        //die($response->get_error_message());
    }

    // cache for an hour
    set_transient('cfTwitterFollowers', $numberOfFollowers, 1*60*60);
    update_option('cfNumberOfFollowers', $numberOfFollowers);
}

return $numberOfFollowers;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It was pretty simple if I just read the documentation anyway...
Instead of followers_count i replaced it with friends_count as outlined in the API 1.1 documentation. :)